# Get all IDENTITY columns in Sybase IQ

Tags: sap-iq

I want a list of all identity columns. Do you know in which system table the information can be found?

BTW: I use Sybase IQ 16

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  C1 INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
  ,C2 INT
)

SELECT * FROM SYS.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TNAME = 'TEST'
```

so the answer is:

```
SELECT
  tname, cname
FROM SYS.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE default_value = 'autoincrement'
```